# When will HtmlUnit Version 3 will be released?

Tags: htmlunit, maven-repository

Can anyone please let me know when will HtmlUnit Version 3 will be released in the maven repository?

Comment: I was confused myself as there are different htmlunit in maven central in 2.x at the time, i.e. this one that seems abandoned: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.htmlunit/htmlunit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HtmlUnit Version 3.1.0 was released at  April 16, 2023.
For Version 3 the groupid was changed.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.htmlunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

As always you can find more info at the homepage https://www.htmlunit.org/.

You can also follow HtmlUnit on twitter https://twitter.com/HtmlUnit

Comment: it is working fine. Could you please let me know if there is canvas support in the latest version ?

Comment: At the moment i have no plans to make a canvas implementation for android. But Pull Requests are very welcome....